# Execution precedence in SQL multi joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, join

Does SQL follow any precedence when executing a query having multiple joins.

A sample query

```
SELECT emp.ename, emp.DEPTNO, emp.JOB, emp.SAL 
FROM EMPLOYEE emp 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT Dept On emp.DEPTNO = Dept.DEPTNO
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(emp.sal) maxSal, emp.DEPTNO 
    FROM EMPLOYEE emp 
    GROUP BY emp.DEPTNO
    ) AS maxSalData
 ON emp.DEPTNO = maxSalData.DEPTNO AND emp.SAL = maxSalData.maxSal
```

My intention of the question is to know, how SQL query gets executed when multiple joins are present.

Comment: The optimiser will put the table with the least rows first no matter the JOIN in order to minimize the data accessed

Comment: @Mihai, product specific. And don't forget about indexes etc.

Comment: Are you asking about SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh Of course,also the statistics issues and so on.Just a general comment to a general question.

Comment: @jarlh I was trying to know about how it generally works, and also the difference in the way it's in oracle and sql-server. Apologies for that i didn't mention it in initial question.

Comment: @RitheshKrishnan, both those products have explain/execution plan functionality. Learn to use these, compare different versions of the same query. Very useful knowledge!

Comment: Database query optimizers are free to re-order query execution as they see fit.

Comment: SQL is a set-based expression, which is "compiled" in to other code for execution.  This "compiled" code is referred to as an "execution plan" in SQL Server and an "explain plan" in Oracle.  The "compilation" takes account of current statistics (which may or may not be up to date), indexes, your query, parameters, and a whole host of other factors.  Exact details on what it does are complex and vary between RDBMS and even versions.  But the short answer is; most optimisers estimate the cost of different options and seek out the lowest estimated cost option.  Including re-ordering your joins.

Comment: @ MatBailie - Thanks for responding, that was really informative.

Answer (score 4):

The optimizer determines the ordering of the joins.

I want to note that there is a simpler way to write the query:

```
SELECT emp.ename, emp.DEPTNO, emp.JOB, emp.SAL 
FROM (SELECT emp.*, MAX(emp.sal) OVER (PARTITION BY emp.DEPTNO) as maxsal
      FROM EMPLOYEE emp
     ) emp;
```

So:

- The `JOIN` to `DEPARTMENT` is not necessary.
- The subquery is not necessary, it can be replaced by a window/analytic function

Hence, the question about the order of processing of joins is misplaced, because a better version of the query doesn't even have explicit `JOIN`s.  However, the answer is that the optimizer determines the execution order of the `JOIN`s.  The intent of SQL as a language is that it is *declarative*, not *procedural*.  That is, it describes the results to be produced, but doesn't specify how that gets done.

Comment: The join to DEPARTMENT would take care of eliminating EMPLOYEE records with invalid department numbers. In *some companies* (don't ask me where! :-) **certain employees** (don't ask me who! :-) are assigned to non-existent departments for ***various reasons***. (Don't ask me why! :-)

Comment: `declarative`; must remember to use that in my explanations.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for responding. The sql that i gave was just an example. There could be many real scenarios where there joins are used more.